# feign.FeignException: status 500 while accessing the remote service through feign call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign

I have an Employee service that returns an employee object in a Response as below -

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
...

@Path("employee")
@RequestScoped
public class Employee {
    @GET
    @Path("/unique")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUniqueEmployeeDetail(
            @QueryParam("useremail") String userEmail,
            @QueryParam("enddateactive") String endDateActive
    ){
        try {
            if ((userEmail == null) || ("".equals(userEmail.trim()))){
                return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity("Input parameter missing: useremail").type(TEXT_HTML).build();
            }
            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date lastDate = new Date();
            String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
 
            if ((endDateActive == null) || (endDateActive.trim().equals(""))){
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                endDateActive = df.format(lastDate);
            }
 
            Employee response = repository.getUniqueEmployeeDetail(userEmail.toLowerCase(), endDateActive);
            return Response.ok(EntityMapper.generate(response)).build();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return Response.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.toString()).type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
        }
    }
 
.....

}
```

The returned Employee object looks like below -

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Employee {
 
    @JsonProperty("EmployeeId")
    private BigDecimal employeeId;
    @JsonProperty("EmployeeName")
    private String employeeName;
    ...
}
```

Now on the client side, I have written a feign client to call the above service to get the employee information. The Data object to receive the response from the above service looks like this -

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class EmployeeDto {
    @JsonProperty("EmployeeId")
    private BigDecimal employeeId;
    @JsonProperty("EmployeeName")
    private String employeeName;
    ...
}
```

And finally, the feign call looks like this -

```
@FeignClient(name = "employee-service", url = "${employee.uri}", configuration = EmpFeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface EmpClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value="/employee/unique", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    EmployeeDto getEmployee(@RequestParam("useremail") String emailAddress);
}
```

Now when I try to invoke this feign client API, the following exception gets thrown. So wanted to check if the above mapping is fine and if I can receive the Response of Employee object from the service in an EmployeeDto like above. Would be grateful if some expert can give me some idea as to where the mapping could be going wrong as the service call is throwing 500 FeignException, as given below -

```
feign.FeignException: status 500 reading EmpClient#getEmployee(String)
        at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:78)
        at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:93)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:149)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36541.getResources(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.mygroup.target.business.PersistenceQueryService.getEmployee(PersistenceQueryService.java:274)
        at com.mycompany.mygroup.target.business.SPATargetService.checkIfTargetExists(SPATargetService.java:307)
        at com.mycompany.mygroup.target.business.SPATargetService.generateTarget(SPATargetService.java:160)
        at com.mycompany.mygroup.target.web.SPATargetResource.createTarget(SPATargetResource.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.apmaas.browser.jsp.BaseFilterWrapper$JspFilter.doFilter(BaseFilterWrapper.java:362)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.security.internal.IDCSSessionSynchronizationFilter.doFilter(IDCSSessionSynchronizationFilter.java:89)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
```

Comment: Enable Feign logs to see the request response logs. this will help you in debugging the 500 Error. To enable logs - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/#feign-logging